# How to detect the type of argument and make it optional correctly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to determine the type of an optional argument. If the argument was specified, the return type should be the same as argument type. Otherwise, the return type must be undefined.

If I wrote `fn<T>(p: T): T`, then the `p` argument is not optional (I can't call the function like this `fn()`). If I make it optional (`fn<T>(p?: T): T`), then I will have to explicitly cast the return type to `T` (`as T`).

```
function fn<T>(p?: T): T {
  return p // Without `as T`
}

const a = fn(1) // Must be `number` or `1`
const b = fn() // Must be `undefined` (without `fn(undefined)`)
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAKgPgBQAcD8AXIugJTHqIDeAsAFCKIBOAplCE0rogPQ+IB1GFAAWcEFEQADAIYBnElPoBfevQgI5kmYgC8yMNgCMpXvwCyILYgBGLaWBABbO0ymI4TaUaV0+jRgA9fDU6DTBrGz0DbFN-S0j7KXAAExZgGDAWFPdsAHdhMQlpFGxU9Mzs0ilSen8A4KA).

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Firstly, you define the two "type functions", the signatures that will indicate, what type of return type you get based on the parameters:

```
function fn(): undefined;
function fn<T>(p: T): T
```

Then, you will define the actual (runtime) implementation.

```
function fn<T>(p?: T): T | undefined {
  return p
}
```